# [IMAGEMAGICK]How to convert the background of a PDF in transparent.?

Tags: pdf, background, png, transparent

A collegue in LATEX-stackoverflow forum answer me to using in imagemagick:

```
convert -density 300 -transparent red in.pdf out.png
```

It works very well with an excellent results, but What can I do if I want make the same with the page 43 of any PDF?.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the page number in brackets:

`convert in.pdf[43] out.png`

Source: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/